# How to remove box and add only underline like the old style for android TextInputLayout in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I want to create the following without setting the style to legacy because it creates other problems for example for AutoCompleteTextView.

`style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"` on FilledBox style TextInputLayout to only have an underline without the box.

Like this :

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="label">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And if you want to remove both box and underline use this : `app:boxBackgroundMode="none"`